# htaccess: Rewrite outdated subdomain to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am a beginner in coding and scripting.

I created a website which used to run at
`preview.my-domain.com`

Now I found some Google entries showing this subdomain. Oops! How do I rewrite

```
preview.my-domain.com
```

to

```
www.my-domain.com
```

The website is located in the same folder on the website, so indeed

```
preview.my-domain.com/[everything here]
```

is absolutely identical to

```
www.my-domain.com/[everything here]
```

Comment: In addition to rewriting, consider [marking up the canonical URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2) as a hint for search engines.

Answer (score 1):

To *redirect* the subdomain to the canonical domain, try the following (mod_rewrite directives) in the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =preview.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. 301 redirects are cached by the browser so can make testing problematic.

The `=` (equals) prefix on the *CondPattern* makes it into a lexicographical string comparison, testing for equality, not a regex (so no need to escape the literal dots or use anchors).

This obviously still requires the `preview` subdomain to be resolvable (ie. defined in DNS).

Comment: wow, thank you. will try that.

Do I need to add this "RewriteEngine On" in front of each rewrite rule? Or does it apply to all following rewrite rules/lines?

Comment: The `RewriteEngine On` directive just needs to appear once in the .htaccess file. It can appear anywhere in the file, although it is more _logical_ if it appears at the top. It can appear multiple times but is unnecessary.